# Data structures and pointers - C code interpretation

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have the following data structure (its name is c); mrb, next and free are 3 pointers.
What does c.mrb.next=c.free mean?
Maybe the pointer mrb points the same object pointed by free?

[image]

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer please mark it

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to answer lacking details.

If `c.mrb.next = c.free` is an equality, then it means the next entry from mrb is the same as free, it's an empty block.

If `c.mrb.next = c.free` means an assignement, then it means you discard every entry you might have after mrb, and place a free slot instead. This would probably be a memory leak if you didn't add those to free before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that now c.mrb will point to the address where c.free is pointing to. Also since you said that mrb and free are pointers, then basically you are doing a pointer to pointer operation. So the code should be like this:

```
c->mrb->next = c->free
```